# Charge iOS device through mains whilst using data cable with laptop

Tags: power, lightning

Take two Apple data sync wires:

1. Cable 1, which connects the iPad to a laptop USB port, and
2. Cable 2, only connected by itself to an iOS data charger socket plugged into the mains, ready to charge any iOS device (not connected to an iOS device)

Is it possible to connect (or solder) the 'power' wires of the two cables (responsible for charging an iOS device) so that the mains can charge the iPad whilst the laptop can transfer data as required to the iPad? Is this feasible without any major complications?

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. Are you wanting to externally charge your iPad (presumably with a charger that will provide more amps than the USB port does) while connected to a computer for syncing?

Comment: Yes that is correct. For the syncing part, it's mainly me programming for the iPad and I wish to externally charge the iPad because as you described, the charger will have more amps than the USB port can provide

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having to deal with a homebrew solution, why not just purchase an externally powered USB hub? For example, the [D-Link DUB-H7](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/connect/usb/dub-h7-7-port-usb-2-0-hub) USB hub is able to provide 1.2 Amps through 2 of its 7 total ports (labeled as 'fast charging' ports). There may also be other hubs out there that will offer the maximum 2 Amps per port.

Comment: This initially sounds like a good suggestion, but I own a DUB-H7 and I found the situation was more complex than I expected.  I found that my iPad (1st gen) would charge from the two "fast charging" ports... but only if my Mac wasn't connected to the hub.  So: I think not possible to charge the iPad and sync with it simultaneously using a DUB-H7.  Sounds strange, but that was my experience.  I found a mention of this on the D-Link site, which mentioned some Windows "iPad_Charge.exe" software to resolve this issue, but I didn't see a Mac version and didn't investigate further.

Comment: @Ashley Hmm...that does sound strange. Well ultimately the DUB-H7 was just the product of a cursory search. I still think there is likely a similar product out there that would get the job done and be much simpler to implement than build a custom cable.